# Django form to change password

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

When a user successfully login and come to home page there is a link "change password" for changing password .It displays a form to change password having three input box for old password, new password confirm new password

Here is my code.

**forms.py**

```
class reset_form(forms.Form):


    oldpassword = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'your old Password',  'class' : 'span'}))
    newpassword1 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'New Password',  'class' : 'span'}))
    newpassword2 = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'password', 'placeholder':'Confirm New Password',  'class' : 'span'}))


    def clean(self):
        if 'newpassword1' in self.cleaned_data and 'newpassword2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['newpassword1'] != self.cleaned_data['newpassword2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**views.py**

---

```
def change_password(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = reset_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newpassword=form.cleaned_data['newpassword1'],
            username=request.user.username
            password=request.user.password

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                user.set_password(newpassword)
                user.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/reset/success/')

            else:
                return render(request, 'reset_password.html',{'error':'You have entered wrong old password','form': form})

        else:
           return render(request, 'reset_password.html',{'error':'You have entered old password','form': form})
    else:
        form = reset_form()
    content = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})  
    return render(request, 'reset_password.html', content,)
```

After submitting the form with correct old password i am getting this message **You have entered wrong old password** I dont know why i am geeting this error message please help with this code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement password change form in Django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256802/how-to-implement-password-change-form-in-django-1-9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason you're using the password field stored in the database, via `request.user`, rather than then one they've actually entered in the form. The database version is hashed, and when you call `authenticate` it hashes it again, so fails to match.

You should be using the value the user enters in the form:

```
username = request.user.username
password = form.cleaned_data['oldpassword']

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for answer it really helped me. But now i am getting another issue my password is changed but to some other text. Now my password is not the old one nor the new password which i have supplied. What i should do ?

Comment: How are you determining that? Don't forget, as I mentioned in the answer, the password is stored hashed in the database.