# How to add CSS classes to Django Built-in forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm using [Django Built-in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms), more precisely the PasswordChangeForm.

It works perfectly until the point where I want it to look like the rest of the website (Bootstrap). 
I followed the approach in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35441042/4470542) that is inheriting the class and built a new one by myself:

```
class PasswordChangeCustomForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    old_password = CharField(required=True,
                  widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'}))

    new_password1 = CharField(required=True,
                  widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'}))

    new_password2 = CharField(required=True,
                  widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'}))
```

But it annoys me to repeat all this code. 
Is there another way to achieve the same thing (add the class `form-control` to the each field) without re-writing each field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the objective of not re-writing the fields, I found out that I could simply update the Widget:

```
class PasswordChangeCustomForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PasswordChangeCustomForm, self).__init__(user, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['old_password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

Particularly useful for Bootstrap (where all fields need the class `form-control`) is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40859744/4470542) from @daniel-roseman:

```
class PasswordChangeCustomForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PasswordChangeCustomForm, self).__init__(user,*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take your code one step further and update all the widgets automatically:

```
super(PasswordChangeCustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
for field in self.fields.values():
    field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Comment: Your code gives a AttributeError `'str' object has no attribute 'widget'`. I resolved it in mine.