# In Django 1.10 include built-in password change form in template and control redirect

Tags: python, django, change-password

my question is a bit similar to what was asked here:
[How to implement password change form in Django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256802/how-to-implement-password-change-form-in-django-1-9)

I try to create a profiles page for my users in Django where in addition to changing the password the user can also unsubscribe from the mailings list etc. In addition, after changing the password I want to redirect to the same page and not the changed_password_done template. I am new to Django and want to do things Django conform. My solution works but I want to be as conform as possible. What I did now is creating a class based view like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm


class EditProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = "profile.html"
    title = "Edit profile"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'title': self.title,
                                                    'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        context = {
            'title': self.title,
            'form': form
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Updating the password logs out all other sessions for the user
            # except the current one.
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            context.update({'updated': True})
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I did not add the other logic like unsubscribe yet but I wanted to know if this is a viable option or if there is a better way to handle the password change request in Django. Should I maybe subclass the form or the password change functionality?

Thanks! Hope it makes sense.

EDIT:

I tried this but the problem is that I can't intercept that the password changed since 'profile' will be reversed to the same URL as the profiles page. Since all POST/GET informations are destroyed there is no way I can know that I was redirected:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_change
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm


class EditProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = "profile.html"
    title = "Edit profile"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'title': self.title,
                                                    'form': form,
                                                    })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return password_change(request, self.template_name, 'profile')
```

Comment: You can add an optional redirect url to the password change function.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. How would a urls.py look like? Is this the solution you had in mind? If so every time a user would directly go to this url even without changing the password it would say so in the profile. Isn't there a better solution?
views.py:
`...
return password_change(request, self.template_name, 'profile_password_changed')
...`


urls.py:
`...
url(r'^profile/$', EditProfile.as_view(), name='profile'),
url(r'^profile/password/changed$', EditProfile.as_view(password_changed=True), name='profile_password_changed'),
...`